# Tight VNC server and Gucamole

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, vnc-server, tightvnc

I have a VM in which I installed the VNC server (TightVNC) using the link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04

It is installed successfully and I can see the port 5901 running

```
/etc/tigervnc$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16460/Xtigervnc     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16183/Xtigervnc     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5901                :::*                    LISTEN      16460/Xtigervnc     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5902                :::*                    LISTEN      16183/Xtigervnc     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36618           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp    29184      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp     7680      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::37372                :::*                                -                   
udp6   20736      0 :::5353                 :::*
```

Now from my local machine, I tried to do the port binding to my local from VM (as per the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l test 172.1.1.1
```

In my local machine, I able to see the port is binded to 5901

```
/etc/guacamole$ fuser 5901/tcp
5901/tcp:            22049
```

Now when I try to take the VNC connection using 127.0.0.1:5901, It promopts for VM's password and shows only the blank page.

[image]

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score -1):

edit your ~/.vnc/xstartup file thus:

```
#!/bin/sh

startxfce4 &
```

I had the same problem and this solved it

For reference i got it from here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52557

Answer (score -2):

You can also try killing and restarting your VNC server

kill $(pgrep Xvnc)
vncserver

Are you trying to VNC from the local machine to the local machine?  I am assuming just for testing correct?

If you are not getting a rejection, at least it should be talking to the service.